# Reasons behind android always booting into twrp insead of system after reset?

Tags: twrp

i have the same problem as this question [How to fix a phone that always boots into TWRP when OS exists](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/228303/how-to-fix-a-phone-that-always-boots-into-twrp-when-os-exists) . Except i did the reset via settings "Erase all" and my device is not samsung. Also i noticed, if i stay in twrp for some time, a small area around/above my charging pin's temperature increase abnormally.

Comment: if no working ROM exist it will always boot into recovery mode. restore your backup

Comment: Okyy. Got the gist.
 Dont have backup sadly but have the sock firmware. Planning on flashing stock recovery as proposed by a xda user.